# Changing system variable path for python doesn't work

Tags: python

I had both Python 2.6 and 2.7 on the computer. In a recent project, I have to use a custom module that is only compatible with Python 2.6. And will need to call this script from TestStand.

The environment variable path was pointing to

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

I removed Python 2.7 completely and changed the variable path to

```
C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Scripts
```

and restarted the computer.

However, it seems that the path is still pointing to python27. Every time I call the scripts from TestStand, it throws the

```
path not found
```

error.

Is there another place I need to change the path?

Comment: Do you also have PYTHONPATH set up?? you might wanna check that too.

Comment: You may also want to look at your file associations for .py files.  How are you launching your script?  `c:\path\to\python.exe myscript.py`, or `myscript.py`?

Comment: Using the Windows installer (.exe or .msi) for Python 2.6 should fix this issue.

Comment: I would install python2.6 in a virtualenv for that project, and be sure to activate it before using TestStand (set PATH, PYTHONPATH and VIRTUAL_ENV, but there's an activate command to do that for you).